# how to access Instagram user profile by using user id instead of username?

Tags: instagram

I need to scrape Instagram by user id number instead of username. How can I do it?

You can access user profile like this

```
https://instagram.com/{username}
```

but I need to access it like below. It doesn't have to be exactly like below. Is it possible to find such path?

```
https://instagram.com/{profile_id}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any possible way to do it.
Anyway, how do you get the `profile_id`. I thought it is not available to be seen anywhere?

Comment: it is available. you can access it via javascript variable called window._sharedData

Comment: @if237912print I see there! But still, I don't think you would be able to do that via web-sracping. You may try using other private APIs written in PHP or Python (I answered it in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/52602041/7498283). You will be able to get user's info my `profile_id`.

Answer (score 0):

you could send a GET request to this url

```
https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/<user_id>/info/
```

from its response you'll get the username and from that you can use your initial url

```
https://instagram.com/<username>/
```